# Octave: PA=LU factorisation

Tags: dataframe, matlab, matrix, compiler-errors, octave

*This question contains edits*

I'm currently trying to obtain a PA=LU factorisation with Octave. Here is my algorythm:

**The main script**:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

%{
We have a square matrix of order 5.
We can show that L4*P4*L3*P3*L2*P2*L1*P1*A = U
With L'4 = L4
L'3 = P2*L3*P4
L'2 = P4*P3*L2*P3*P4
L'1 = P4*P3*P2*L1*P2*P3*P4
and L = \prod L'i^-1
P = P4*P3*P2*P1

Then, for n = 5, we find Pi and Li with:

Pi = eye(n);
Pi([i, n], i) = Pi([n, i], i);

Li = eye(5);
Li(i+1:n, i) = -A(i+1:n, i)/A(i, i); % We divide by the pivot

We will write a function "pli(A, i, n, LorP)" for that.
%}

A = [2 6 5 1 7; ...
     6 9 2 2 3; ...
     7 9 0 6 5; ...
     1 1 6 6 7; ...
     2 7 7 3 9]; % the given matrix
     
Asv = A; % because we will change the value of A

P1 = pli(A, 1, 5, "P")
A = P1*A;
L1 = pli(A, 1, 5, "L")
A = L1*A;
     
P2 = pli(A, 2, 5, "P")
A = P2*A;
L2 = pli(A, 2, 5, "L")
A = L2*A;

P3 = pli(A, 3, 5, "P")
A = P3*A;
L3 = pli(A, 3, 5, "L")
A = L3*A;

P4 = pli(A, 4, 5, "P")
A = P4*A;
L4 = pli(A, 4, 5, "L")
A = L4*A;

P = P4*P3*P2*P1

Lp4 = L4;
Lp3 = P2*L3*P4;
Lp2 = P4*P3*L2*P3*P4;
Lp1 = P4*P3*P2*L1*P2*P3*P4;

L = eye(5);
L(1:5, 1) = Lp1(1:5, 1);
L(2:5, 2) = Lp2(2:5, 2);
L(3:5, 3) = Lp3(3:5, 3);
L(4:5, 4) = Lp4(4:5, 4);
L

U = A

% Verification:

[l u p] = lu(Asv);
norm(p-P)
norm(l-L)
norm(u-U)
```

**The function** `pli(A, i, n, LorP)`:

```
function Mi = pli(A, i, n, LorP)
  % order n
  
  if LorP == "P"
    Pi = eye(n);
    Pi([i, n], i) = Pi([n, i], i); % matrix of elementary permutations
    Mi = Pi;
  elseif LorP == "L"
    Li = eye(5);
    Li(i+1:n, i) = -A(i+1:n, i)/A(i, i); % Devide by the pivot
    Mi = Li;
  else
    error("Wrong entry for 'LorP'")
  endif

endfunction
```

When I execute my code, I obtain strange infinite values, and don't understand why, and how to solve it:

```
P1 =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   1   0   0   0   1

L1 =

     1     0     0     0     0
  -Inf     1     0     0     0
  -Inf     0     1     0     0
  -Inf     0     0     1     0
  -Inf     0     0     0     1

P2 =

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   1

L2 =

     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0   NaN     1     0     0
     0   NaN     0     1     0
     0   NaN     0     0     1

P3 =

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   1   0   1

L3 =

     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0   NaN     1     0
     0     0   NaN     0     1

P4 =

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   1

L4 =

     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0   NaN     1

P =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   1   1

L =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

U =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

ans = 2.2361
DLASCL: parameter number 4 is invalid
error: Fortran procedure terminated by call to XERBLA
error: called from
    q1a at line 69 column 1
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT (related to the answer of @BillBokeey)**

After changing `pli.m` into:

```
function Mi = pli(A, i, n, LorP)
  % order n
  
  if LorP == "P"

    Pi = eye(n);

    if(A(i, i)==0)

         idx_Pvt = find(diag(A)~=0,1); % Find index of first nonzero pivot

         Pi([i, idx_Pvt], [i,idx_Pvt]) = [0 1;1 0];
    end

    Mi = Pi;
  elseif LorP == "L"
    Li = eye(5);
    Li(i+1:n, i) = -A(i+1:n, i)/A(i, i); % Devide by the pivot
    Mi = Li;
  else
    error("Wrong entry for 'LorP'")
  endif

endfunction
```

the answer becomes:

```
P1 =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1

L1 =

   1.000000000000000                   0                   0                   0                   0
  -3.000000000000000   1.000000000000000                   0                   0                   0
  -3.500000000000000                   0   1.000000000000000                   0                   0
  -0.500000000000000                   0                   0   1.000000000000000                   0
  -1.000000000000000                   0                   0                   0   1.000000000000000

P2 =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1

L2 =

   1.000000000000000                   0                   0                   0                   0
                   0   1.000000000000000                   0                   0                   0
                   0  -1.333333333333333   1.000000000000000                   0                   0
                   0  -0.222222222222222                   0   1.000000000000000                   0
                   0   0.111111111111111                   0                   0   1.000000000000000

P3 =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1

L3 =

   1.000000000000000e+00                       0                       0                       0                       0
                       0   1.000000000000000e+00                       0                       0                       0
                       0                       0   1.000000000000000e+00                       0                       0
                       0                       0   3.833333333333307e+01   1.000000000000000e+00                       0
                       0                       0   3.333333333333310e+00                       0   1.000000000000000e+00

P4 =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1

L4 =

   1.000000000000000                   0                   0                   0                   0
                   0   1.000000000000000                   0                   0                   0
                   0                   0   1.000000000000000                   0                   0
                   0                   0                   0   1.000000000000000                   0
                   0                   0                   0  -0.096069868995633   1.000000000000000

P =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1

L =

   1.000000000000000e+00                       0                       0                       0                       0
  -3.000000000000000e+00   1.000000000000000e+00                       0                       0                       0
  -3.500000000000000e+00  -1.333333333333333e+00   1.000000000000000e+00                       0                       0
  -5.000000000000000e-01  -2.222222222222222e-01   3.833333333333307e+01   1.000000000000000e+00                       0
  -1.000000000000000e+00   1.111111111111111e-01   3.333333333333310e+00  -9.606986899563325e-02   1.000000000000000e+00

U =

   2.000000000000000e+00   6.000000000000000e+00   5.000000000000000e+00   1.000000000000000e+00   7.000000000000000e+00
                       0  -9.000000000000000e+00  -1.300000000000000e+01  -1.000000000000000e+00  -1.800000000000000e+01
                       0                       0  -1.666666666666679e-01   3.833333333333333e+00   4.500000000000000e+00
                       0                       0                       0   1.526666666666656e+02   1.799999999999988e+02
                       0                       0                       0   1.776356839400250e-15  -2.292576419213974e+00

ans = 1.902113032590308
ans = 38.52133878794479
ans = 241.8726657311275
```

Comment: Your matrix `P1` is not a permutation matrix (You have no 1s on the first row and two 1s on the last row). Also, you don't necessarily need to permute your matrix A at every step, just when the pivot is nil.

Comment: What you need to do, in your `pli` function, is to first check if the current pivot is nil. If it is not, your matrix P will be the identity matrix. If the pivot is nil, you need to find another non zero pivot and output the corresponding permutation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your algorithm is that your matrix P is not a permutation matrix (e. g. for P1, You have no 1s on the first row and two 1s on the last row).

Furthermore, you don't necessarily need to permute your matrix A at every step, just when the pivot is nil. This is the reason why the permutation matrix is here in the first place

Both these problem can be solved by modifying your function `pli` :

```
function Mi = pli(A, i, n, LorP)
  % order n
  
  if strcmp(LorP,"P")

    Pi = eye(n);

    if(A(i, i)==0)

         idx_Pvt = find(diag(A)~=0,1); % Find index of first nonzero pivot

         Pi([i, idx_Pvt], [i,idx_Pvt]) = [0 1;1 0];
    end

    Mi = Pi;

  elseif strcmp(LorP,"L")

    Li = eye(5);
    Li(i+1:n, i) = -A(i+1:n, i)/A(i, i); % Devide by the pivot
    Mi = Li;
  
  else

    error("Wrong entry for 'LorP'")

  endif

endfunction
```

Like I said in one of my comment, you also need to modify your main in order to build the `L` ans `U` matrices correctly. Here is a (non-optimised) MATLAB example of how to do this, which should work in Octave after a small amount of modifications:

```
A = [2 6 5 1 7; ...
     6 9 2 2 3; ...
     7 9 0 6 5; ...
     1 1 6 6 7; ...
     2 7 7 3 9]; % the given matrix
 
 [sz1,~] = size(A);
  
 A_ite = A;
 
 L_out = eye(sz1);
 
 L_Save = zeros(sz1,sz1,sz1);
 
 for ii=1:sz1
     
    % Calculate Pi
    Pi = pli(A_ite, ii, sz1, 'P');
    
    A_ite = Pi*A_ite;
    
    Li = pli(A_ite,ii,sz1,'L');
    
    A_ite = Li*A_ite;
    
    L_Save(:,:,ii) = (Li-eye(sz1));
    
    L_out = Li*Pi*L_out;
     
 end
 
 U = A_ite;
 
 L = -sum(L_Save,3)+eye(sz1);
 
 norm(A-L*U)
```

You can also find an efficient version of the algorithm at the end of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)

Comment: ```
 >>> error: parse error near line 11 of file ...\pli.m

  syntax error

>>>          idx_Pvt = find(diag(A)<>0,1); % Find index of first nonzero pivot
                                                       ^
>> 
```

Comment: I get this error message (the "^" is below the ">")

Comment: What about now?

Comment: I edited my post with your answer, I don't have code errors anymore or infinite values, but the 3 values at the end ("ans = ...") show that the matrices found are not correct. Seems like P stays unchanged =`eye(5)`

Comment: I also edited the main script so the results apppear

Comment: Well, the LU decomposition is not necessarily unique, hence the difference in outputs. If you want to check that it is a correct LU decomposition, I'd suggest checking the value of `norm(Asv-L*U) `

Comment: `norm(Asv - L*U) = 455.6279575943086`... Thanks anyway !

Comment: You are building your final output matrices wrong... I'll add it to the answer